# How do I fix "Unable to load template..." error in Word 2013?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-word-2013

On loading Word I get error message;

> Unable to load template $ndeley-1.9.2 dotm (a Mendeley prog).

If I dismiss this error 4 times Word loads.
How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What are you deleting 4 times?

Comment: I tried reinstalling Mendeley

Comment: So the error message is "Unable to load template $ndeley-1.9.2 dotm" ?

Comment: I delete the error message always 4 times and Word loads as normal

Comment: Welcome to Super User! More details are needed. Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. Take a minute to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Control Panel.

   ```
   In Windows 8, on the Start screen, type Control Panel, and select Control Panel in the search results.
   ```
2. Click Programs > Programs and Features.
3. Click the Office application you want to repair, and then click Change.
4. In Office 2013, click either Quick Repair or Online Repair. In Office 2010, click Repair > Continue.

This is most likely caused because of a corrupt template that was previously downloaded. This should fix your issue, if not, try doing a system restore to the last day it was working properly.

Comment: You may need to rename the bad template e.g. to " $ndeley-1.9.2 dotm.broken"(rather than delete it, in case you need it again). Word will regenerate the default templates.